# OSX: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, permissions, zsh

on my mac os system (v. 10.9.3) I wanted to uninstall my zsh so first of all I executed the uninstall script in zsh.
This failed so I wanted to delete the affected files by my own and am stuck here.

Everytime i try to rm the .oh-my-zsh directory or the .zsh_history (or any other file) file i get :

```
rm: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh: Operation not permitted
```

I already tried to check for osx flags, but no flags are set (with ls -lO).

Also I tried to give the directory full permission (755) but the deletion also fails.

Does anybody know how to deal with this?
Thanks a lot.

---

EDIT:

see answer, was able to resolve this on my own.

Comment: Try running `fuser .oh-my-zsh` to see if the file is opened by some process. I'm not sure if OSX has the `fuser` command though.

Comment: OSX hat his command but it says its not opened by others..

Comment: Which shell are you using to do this?

Comment: I reverted to bash (with chsh -s /bin/bash and source /etc/profile)

Comment: Have you rebooted after `chsh`? Otherwise zsh will be running probably multiple times in the background. (I wonder, however, why this is preventing you from deleting these files -- at least Linux does not care about removing opened files, I thought OSX will behave similar.)

Comment: yep, rebooted multiple times. even tried to delete the files in the single user and safe mode, but still the same problem. seems to be a osx related problem ...

Comment: @maksim Please consider posting your solution as an answer and maybe cleaning up the question to be more general (as it seems to be not specific to oh-my-zsh). So people with the same or similar problems will find it and not ignore it for beliefing it to be without answer. You may also accept your own answers.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i was able to resolve this on my own..

Somehow I had the nouchg flag on my home directory. So not the files inside had this flag but the Users/username directory.

So doing this:

```
sudo chflags nouchg username/
```

i was able to delete the files.

Thanks for your input.